# solving a Schrödinger eqution and checking my logic...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know people have asked this kind of stuff before here but I just want to check some work, and see what I am doing wrong. I suspect it's pretty easy. Hope this isn't too long.

So we have a particle in a box, with the boundaries at -L/2 and L/2. We assume the potential well is infinite. So the potential energy part of the equation is zero inside the box for (-L/2) 0 inside the box and zero outside.

Schrödinger is: $\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}=-\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}E\psi$

And since E>0 the coefficient on the front of the RHS can be written as is negative, but we can still call it a constant, $-k^2$. So $-k^2 = \frac{-2m}{\hbar^2}$

That means the solution is going to be $A\sin kx + B\cos kx = \psi(x)$.

Since the box limits are L/2 and -L/2 then $\psi\left(\frac{L}{2}\right)=0$ and $\psi\left(\frac{-L}{2}\right)=0$.

Which means that $A\sin k\frac{-L}{2} + B\cos k\frac{-L}{2} = A\sin k\frac{L}{2} + B\cos k\frac{L}{2}=0$

For the first part of this it's clear that if $A\sin k\frac{-L}{2} + B\cos k\frac{-L}{2}$ then $A\sin k\frac{-L}{2} = -B\cos k\frac{-L}{2}$ but that can't happen so one of these (A or B) has to be zero.

Let's assume A isn't the one that is zero, and B is. So for that to be the case $A\sin k\frac{-L}{2} =0$ which means that $k\frac{-L}{2}=0$ or it is a multiple of $\pi$. But the thing is at that value -- -L/2, this would give k a value of zero. So this doesn't seem to work.

Now we go to B being the one that isn't zero. In that case we have $B\cos k\frac{-L}{2} =0$ which means that $k\frac{-L}{2} = \frac{n\pi}{2}$ which gets us a value of $\frac{-n\pi}{L}$ for k.

So we have $\psi(x) = B \cos\left(\frac{-n\pi x}{L}\right)$

That satisfies the boundary condition and Differentiating twice we have $\psi''=B \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)^2 \cos\left(\frac{-n\pi x}{L}\right)$

And this is where i feel like I am a bit stuck in finding B. I know that we earlier said $k^2 =  \frac{-2m}{\hbar^2}$ so does that mean we set $\frac{\sqrt{-2m}}{\hbar}=\frac{-n\pi}{L}$? Or do we say that $B \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)^2=\frac{-2m}{\hbar^2}$?

I know this seems a really long post, and I am sorry, but I wanted to show the work and be explicit about the steps. Especially since I bet I am missing a stupid elementary thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically got it down, but let me say a few things. First off, notice the symmetry of the boundary conditions. From this you can deduce that you want an even function on $[ -L /2 , L /2]$. An easy way to show this: change the boundary condition to $[0,L]$ and shift by $L/2$. Now we have

$$B \cos ( kL/2 ) = 0$$

We don't want the trivial solution (i.e $B=0$), so we deduce that

$$ kL /2 = (n +\frac{1}{2} ) \pi$$

for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. To find $B$, we have one more piece of information...

$$ \int_{-L/2}^{L/2} \psi(x)^2 dx = 1 $$

Normalization!! Using that, it's easy to find out what $B$, I think you should get

$$ \psi_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \cos \left ( \frac{ ( 2n+1) \pi}{L} x \right ) $$

Comment: Thanks, and just to make sure I am reading you right, the integration we do to get the normalization constant is $\int^{L/2}_{-L/2} \cos^2(x)dx = 1$, yes?

Comment: It's $ L/2 =\int \cos^2 (kx)dx \implies B^2= 2/L $. ( since we want the integral to actually be one, we need to divide by $2/L$ and that is what fixes $B$